# what is difference between .subscribe() without observable and with observable in latest angular?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

What is .subscribe() method in angular , I learnt that its operator or method from rxjs but I dont see any import when I use it like:

```
showConfig() {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl)
      // .subscribe(data => console.log('data',data));
      .subscribe(data => this.dataValues = data);
 }
```

And Yes It will be working with rxjs's operator observable too after importing it but I dont have any idea why people saying .subscribe() is a operator in rxjs .

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Config {
  title: string;
  body: string;
}


showConfig() {
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
    .subscribe((data: Config) => this.dataValues = data);
}
```

Comment: `subscribe` is not an operator.

Comment: @cartant, thanks for replying, so what is .subscribe() ? or can you check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subscribe and tell me "return this.http.get(this.configUrl)" will this code return observable?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link for information about the "subscribe" method: 
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable#subscribe

And this link about the Observable class: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable

In simple words "subscribe" is a method on a "Observable" class.

You imported it with this line:

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Edit:

In your case you don't need to import it directly. Since http.get will return/create it for you. Importing Observable like that is needed when you want to create an Observable something like Observable.create(...

Comment: But I am confused what is .subscribe() even. As I have this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subscribe . I am using .subscribe() method without importing anything from rxjs and my code works fine too

Comment: this.http.get() will return an Observable. And on that observable object you call one of it's methods called 'subscribe'. Your code works because you imported the Observable class and that class has the method 'subscribe' too.

Comment: so .subscribe() , Is it a method from rxjs or from angular?

Comment: .subscribe is a method on Observable class which comes from rxjs. Angular as a framework uses rxjs in its' HttpClient.

Comment: sorry to bother you again , so you are saying "return this.http.get(this.configUrl)" code return observable even if I dont write with " return this.http.get<Config[]>(this.configUrl)"

Comment: Yes. You can delete the "return" keyword and everything will work.

Comment: If I get observable from "return this.http.get(this.configUrl)" code . so do I need to import Observable and do code like "return this.http.get<any[]>(this.configUrl)" . It will be really helpful for me to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186635/discussion-between-robert-and-manish-vashisth).